# Consolidating Firebase messaging and Google Analytics in Xamarin Forms Android project

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-analytics-firebase

In our Xamarin Forms app we have been using Firebase for push notifications for few years. For that purpose, we have a project in Firebase Console.

Now I needed to add Google Analytics (GA4) functionality. Based on documentation, in https://analytics.google.com/ I created a property for our project, and added a data stream for Android platform (and another data stream for iOS also, by the way). That allowed me to download a config file google-services.json to be added to the app project. A new project corresponding to the newly created data stream appeared in the Firebase console.

The problem is that the app project already has google-services.json file used for the push notifications. If I replace it with the new google-services.json, push notifications stop working. If I leave the existing google-services.json, GA4 would not work.

Of course, the google-services.json files differ. The project_number, project_id, storage_bucket, client_id etc are different, and the existing file has

```
    "firebase_url": "https://api-1234567891482864589-273909.firebaseio.com",
```

which does not exist in the new file. The package_name is the same in both files.

How can I consolidate the projects to make both Firebase functionalities work? I would prefer to keep the newest project.

Answer (score 0):

From document [GA4] Firebase integration
[Link Google Analytics 4 properties to Firebase](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234#linkga), we could find that :

> **Create a project**
>
> When you create a project in Firebase, you have the option to
> integrate with Analytics. If you already have one or more Google
> Analytics accounts, you can associate your project with one of those.
> If you do not already have a Google Analytics Account, a new one will
> be created for you with the name Default Account for Firebase.
>
> Firebase users who have access to that project are given Analytics
> user roles based on their Firebase roles (see [User access](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234#access) above).

For more, you can check Part : **Link your Firebase project to Analytics** in above link.

The steps:

**Set up a new Analytics link**

- Open your Firebase project.
- Open Project settings > Integrations.
- On the Google Analytics card, click Link.
- Select an Analytics Account or create a new one.

  If you select an existing account, you have the option to select an existing Google Analytics 4 property in that account or to create a new property.

  If you create a new account, then a new Google Analytics 4 property is created for you and your project is linked to that property.
  Learn more about setup and limits
- Configure your Analytics settings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I don't see how I can make the project that already works with Analytics work with push notifications. Can you help on that?